# Order records in table by other table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have 3 tables: `articles`, `people` and `person_mentions`.

`Article` model `has_many :people, through: person_mentions` and so on.

In `person_mentions` table I have 3 columns `article_id`, `person_id` and `mention_order`. `mention_order` is an integer.

I need to find all people, who mentioned in article and order them by `mention_order`, but when I run

```
@article.people.order(mention_order: :asc)
```

I get an error

> column people.mention_order does not exist

So, I need to make a query from `people` table with `mention_order` from `person_mentions` in it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try:

```
@article.people.order("person_mentions.mention_order asc")
```

Comment: Assuming you are using mysql, as of 5.7, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES is enforced and this solution will not work anymore. This is because person_mentions is not in the select clause and therefore cannot be used to order. I'm still looking for a solution.